# Duration of Service Worker Registration for Samsung Internet Push Notifications

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, service-worker

I'm trying to build a web application that will send push notifications to a user who subscribes to it (testing on Samsung Internet). However, I'm facing an issue where after several hours, the phone stops receiving the push notifications, and I will need to re-open the web application and re-subscribe to resume receiving push notifications. Below is the code for my service worker and its registration:

Service Worker:

```
var windowActive = true;
var numMessages = 0;
var sAdder;


self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
  // console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: "${event.data.text()}"`);

  console.log(windowActive);

  numMessages++;

  if(numMessages == 1) {
    sAdder = "";
  } else {
    sAdder = "s";
  }

  var title = 'Convers8te';
  var options = {
    body: numMessages + ' message' + sAdder + ' received!',
    icon: '/images/logo/8-icon.png',
    badge: '/images/badge.png',
    tag: 'c8t',
  };

  if(windowActive == false) {
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
  }

});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received.');

  event.notification.close();
  numMessages = 0;

  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow('')
  );
});

self.addEventListener('message', function (evt) {
  windowActive = evt.data['windowActive'];
  console.log('postMessage received', evt.data);
});
```

Registration:

```
function subscribeUser() {
  const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
  swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
  })
  .then(function(subscription) {
    console.log('User is subscribed.');

    updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription);

    isSubscribed = true;

    updateBtn();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);
    updateBtn();
  });
}
```

Update subscription on server then sends the push token to the server to be used through the Firebase service.

I've tried several things such as lengthening the session duration, and testing on several other devices but it seems to stop receiving push notifications after several hours.

Also, a side question is whether it is possible for push notifications work even when the Samsung Internet explorer app is closed? Currently they only work for me when the tab is closed, but not when the entire app is closed.

Thanks for taking the time to read and help!